# How to wait for element that scrolls onto page

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

- As a user
- When I go to a page
- Then there is an element that scrolls down into view

There is a `link` I want to `click` on that element.
Sometimes it will work but how do I wait for it to finish scrolling down and then `click` on the element?

`Thread.sleep(1000)` works but I want to know is there a better approach?

Tools I am using:

```
Java
Selenium
```

Comment: This scroll is performed by Selenium or how? Can you add some code to see how you try to perform click on element?

Answer (score 2):

Use webdriver wait until the element visible or click able.Try the below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Id here"))).click();
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Id here"))).click();
```

Please Note: Instead of ID you can put any locator like xpath,class,CSS.I have provided one example of ID here.

Comment: this is the best practice for selenium!

Comment: Please @Kajal Don't answer the question which are already answered you can mark duplicate reputation doesn't matter

Comment: Please make sure that next time, otherwise their are peoples who are over-smart and down vote you, they don't see the efforts had you made to wrote the answer..

Comment: Sure mate.I have noted.